# Core Data: Fetching related objects in many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to wrap my head around the proper architecture/pattern for this situation:

I've got two entities, `Book` and `Library`s. They each have a many-to-many relationship to the other (`Book`s can be in many `Library`s, and a `Library` will have many `Book`s.

One of my views lists books in a particular library. I have a controller class that handles fetching of this data and provides it to my view. To do that, I'm planning on using an `NSFetchRequest` for all `Book` entities, filtered by a predicate that fetches only books in a specific `Library`. But I can't seem to find the proper way to format the predicate for this fetch request.

I also investigated simply accessing `Library`'s `books` accessor to get access to the appropriate books without having to fetch anything (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145178/core-data-fetching-objects-that-are-in-relationship-to-another-object)), but I want to use `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` so my controller is notified about any changes to the fetched objects, and can notify the view. I considered just listening for `NSManagedObjectContextDidChangeObjectsNotification`, but this will deliver notifications for every single change in the context, even if it's not for relevant entities.

How have you handled situations like this in the past?

Comment: Worth reading this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527966/how-to-create-an-nsfetchrequest-which-filters-core-data-objects-based-on-attribu

Comment: Can you show some code? How does your `NSFetchRequest` / its `NSPredicate` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fetch request / predicate could look something like this:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Book> = Book.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS %@", #keyPath(Book.libraries), library)

// Another option:
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF IN %@", library.books!)
```

Comment: I had no idea `CONTAINS` could be used with a set like this! [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) say that it's a String comparison operator, but this usage makes total sense. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnWickham I added an alternative way. You're welcome. :)